Are there multiple d-spacings due to a single diffraction plane in XRD?
The Bragg Law is
$$n \lambda=2d \sin(\theta) $$
Therefore, you can find the d-spacing of a given diffraction plane if you know the wavelength and angle by:
$$ d = \frac{n \lambda}{2 \sin \theta}$$
But $n \in \mathbb N$, so that implies that we can pick several different values for N, finding several different peaks that all have the same angle but different d-spacing?
While obviously these would all have the same XRD peak location, it matters for solving for the unit cell parameters, as the d-spacing is directly important for that application.

Not exactly sure what you mean here.  $d$ is determined by the underlying lattice structure, so there are only certain $d$'s that are allowed, determined by the Bragg plane you are scattering off of. So while you can fix $\theta$ and vary $n$ to get different $d$'s, it would be a happy coincidence if any of these happened to correspond to other crystal planes in the lattice. Such coincidences do occur, but they are rare.
